# Buy a domain with azure, error with contact information

Tags: azure

When I want to buy a domain with azure, I always have a problem with the contact information validition on the "state" input for Belgium,

I already tried many time since more than a week but the error still show up

[image: Screen of the error]

Does someone know what can I do for pass through this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to provide the province instead of Belgium. Belgium is the country and the in the State or territory field you need to provide the province.

I just tested and it needs the ISO-3166-2:BE code: [Wikipedia for ISO code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provinces_of_Belgium)

I'll send them a note to fix it.

Comment: Like I said I already tried many options:
- Belgium
- Brabant Wallon
- BW
- BE
- ...